# Forcing Interactive R session

Tags: r

How does one run an R script forcing the session to be interactive. The docs in `?interative` say that `--ess` and `--interactive` control this, but I don't see any effect.

Windows:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin>R  -e "interactive()" --ess -s
[1] FALSE
```

Mac:

```
$ R -e "interactive()" --interactive -s
[1] FALSE
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT:
I suppose on can hack the base namespace which may work for some things (like install.packages). But this is a poor excuse for a solution...

```
$ R -e "unlockBinding('interactive',as.environment('package:base'));assign('interactive',function() TRUE,envir=as.environment('package:base'));base::interactive()" --interactive -s
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Why do you need to run a script where `interactive()` is true?

Comment: If you need user input, you can use `file("stdin")`. This is different than using `stdin()`, which will be skipped over when running a script.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde: It comes up for some other things like default graphics devices and what not.

Comment: Here's a use-case @Matthew Plourde: I am using Hadley Wickham's testthat library to automate testing a package I'm developing. To help interactive users deal with some not-quite-obvious behavior I want one of the functions in my package to issue a message to interactive users (but not clutter up the consoles of automated scripts) the first time they invoke the function. Unfortunately, when using automated testing via auto_test, R is (correctly) reporting interactive() as FALSE. Using Ian Fellows' trick I was able to create a test which fakes interactive mode to ensure the message works.

Answer (score 5):

That had come up with our beloved [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) alternative to `Rscript`, and I then added a toggle:

```
edd@max:~$ r -p -e 'interactive()'
[1] FALSE
edd@max:~$ r -i -p -e 'interactive()'
[1] TRUE
edd@max:~$
```

It may well be that `R` when invoked as you do always sets it to false.

Comment: humm,... so what is the point of the R command args if they don't do what they say?